# C++ escape character difference in osx and windows?

Tags: c++

I'm playing around with C++ in xcode and well i'm having an issue with

```
char array[] = "Apple";
```

Technically a null escape '\0' is automatically added. I'm just writing a basic function to add the number of letters in the c-string but i go into a forever loop because it can't find the '\0'. Why is that? I'm using g++.

```
int CharLength(char* word)
{
    char* temp = word;
    int count = 0 ;

    while ( temp != '\0' )
    {
        temp++;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: You're not dereferencing your pointer to figure out what it's pointing at. And there is a perfectly good function to do that already called `strlen`. And your compiler will generally generate much faster code for a call to `strlen` than you could ever hope to code yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to dereference.

```
while ( *temp != '\0' )
```

Comment: @Omnifarious: Read words two and three of the question again.

Comment: 'escape character'? Yeah, what about those two words?

Comment: @Omnifarious: C'mon, you're going to tell me that you can't tell the difference between the title and the question? Really?

Comment: @Omni: Of the _first sentence,_ ya goose :-) +1'ing since this is the correct answer to the _question!_ You can wax lyrical about `strlen` or `std::string` or even a better language for processing string (Perl, anyone?) but that doesn't change the fact that this answer solves the specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

"`temp`" will not be 0 until you've looked at all of memory and wrapped around! On the other hand `*temp` will be zero when you get to the end of the string. The loop condition should be

```
while ( *temp != '\0' )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use strlen from the <cstring> or <string.h> headers.

Comment: Missed the fact that he is comparing the pointer, not the pointed-to char.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill: It's still a better answer than yours. Yes, that's a mistake that was made. But the real mistake was not using `strlen` in the first place.

Comment: You forgot about `std::string`.

Comment: @Omni: well, since the question seems to be messing about with how `strlen` might be implemented, I think recommending the use of `strlen` is less than helpful. Also, I believe this answer was originally an explanation of why RoR's code ought to work fine -- this answer bears zero resemblance to what it was when I downvoted.